# FOSUserBundle registration customize

Tags: php, symfony, registration, fosuserbundle

What I am trying to do is nothing hard. This is my first project on symfony and it's really confusing.

I am using FOSUSerbundle. I dont want to have a login and registration bellow `/login` and `/registration`

So I made a bundle which  is child of FOSUSerbundle ... and it overrides its twigs.

I have ::base.html.twig where I include header.html.twig and there I have: `{% render 'FOSUserBundle:Security:login' %}` which render my teplate (overrided the FOS one) works gr8. Even the errors after submiting are rendering on the ::base template bellow "/" route.

```
#Security.yml
    form_login:
        check_path: /login_check
        login_path: /
        provider: fos_userbundle
```

Works great.

And I need to do exactly that same for my registration.

So in `::base` I include `welcome_page.html.twig` where I code `{% render 'FOSUserBundle:Registration:register' %}` and there I have under my rewrited template: `WelcomePageBundle:Registration:register.html.twig` this:

```
{% block fos_user_content %}
{% include "FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}[/code]
```

which also include from MY rewrited bundle: `WelcomePageBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig` this:

```
{% for key, message in app.session.getFlashes() %}
<div class="{{ key }}">
    {{ message|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
</div>
{% endfor %}

<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" id="register_form">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <input type="submit" class="registration_submit" value="{{     'welcome_page.registration_box.register_submit'|trans }}"/>
</form>

<div class="v_pripade">
    {{ 'welcome_page.registration_box.with_reg_problems'|trans }}
    <span style='color: #fff568'>{{ 'welcome_page.registration_box.with_reg_problems_part2'|trans }}</span>
</div>
```

Everything works like a charm... all the files are included and displayed greate. But the problem comes now.

When I go to route `/register`

(which is basic route from FOS bundle)

```
<route id="fos_user_registration_register" pattern="/register">
  <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Registration:register</default>
</route>
```

... fill data and click submit... it works. The errors are displayed or registration is succes..

But when I submit form from my route `/` where the registration controller is rendered (rendered ok) it takes my to this route `:/register` which is normal behaviour because this path:

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form)    }} method="POST" id="register_form">
```

... this site isn't extended by nothing so its just clean form on white page with errors... OK

But how can I possible make work this form with displaying errors and success ON MY ::base template like the login? and dont go to `/register` route? I tried replace `/register` for `/` which bring me to my `::base` template (like in login I do).

```
#security.yml
form_login:
    check_path: /login_check
    login_path: /
    provider: fos_userbundle
```

But none of the errors or success are displayed ...

Do anyone know solution?

Comment: Have you tried to change fos_user_register route that includes registration.xml from the bundle and prefix it (the route) with / instead of /register? Looks like you just created another route which directs to the register controller.

Comment: Did you get this working properly? And was it Vadim's suggestion which resolved the problem for you?

Answer (score 4):

You'll find the official documentation about how to override default FOSUserBundle controllers at 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html

Create a controller for your homepage and forward requests (http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/controller.html#forwarding) to FOSUserBundle registration controller or add logic to your own controller after doing whatever FOSUserBundle does at registration:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Controller;

// Imports @route annotation 
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class CustomRegistrationController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function register() {
        $response = $this->forward('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

or

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function registerAction()
    {
        $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
        $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
        $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

        $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
        if ($process) {
            $user = $form->getData();

            /*****************************************************
             * Add new functionality (e.g. log the registration) *
             *****************************************************/
            $this->container->get('logger')->info(
                sprintf('New user registration: %s', $user)
            );

            if ($confirmationEnabled) {
                $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
            } else {
                $this->authenticateUser($user);
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
            }

            $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');
            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);

            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```